# How to implement image tooltip like this in android?

Tags: android

[imagetooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J1yG.jpg)

Whenever click an image, I wanna show tooltip like this.

Can anyone tell me How to implement this please?

Comment: I found solution for Xamarin see here [link](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: @EminNiftiyev Thx!

Comment: if it worked, i deserve USEFUL :)